# How can I initialize table in quill js 2.0.?

Tags: javascript, quill

How can I initialize table in quill js 2.0.?

I've tried by using table keyword in **toolbar** it shows table icon but I could not create the table.

[image]

Comment: Did you ever find a solution that allowed you to use the table module from controls in the toolbar?

Answer (score 7):

Try to provide table module when creating your editor like this:

```
var editor = new Quill( '#editor', {
    theme: 'snow',
    modules: {
        table: true
    }
} );
```

And then just reference table module:

```
const table = editor.getModule('table');
```

Using table variable you can trigger different methods for tables:

```
table.insertTable(2, 2);
```

Full example can be found here: https://codepen.io/quill/pen/QxypzX

Comment: This works, but why are the buttons outside of the toolbar? Is the module unfinished? Issue queue is really hard to follow on this.

Comment: this is not very useful, as when you try to add a bullet list in a cell, it does not. IT actually write as separate line outside the table. Try in your fiddle.

Answer (score 4):

I really like the extensibility of Quill a lot.
I implement a module [quill-better-table](https://github.com/soccerloway/quill-better-table) to add support for tables.
Hope that quill-better-table could help someone who need to edit/render table in quilljs.
Requirements: quill.js v2.0.0-dev.3

Comment: this is not very useful, as when you try to add a bullet list in a cell, it does not. IT actually write as separate line outside the table. Try in your codepen example..

Comment: this should be marked as answer